# Counting distinct values within an aggregate function

Tags: sql

I have a table of stores, orders, items, quantity ordered and quantity shipped.  I want to create a summary by store of the number of unique orders where the quantity shipped was less than the quantity ordered on one or more items within the order.  For example:

```
Store   OrderID ItemID  Ordered Shipped  
A          1      1        5      5  
A          1      2        2      0  
A          2      5        6      4  
A          2      2        4      4  
B          1      6        2      2  
B          1      12       1      1  
B          1      18       4      4  
B          2      8        2      2  
B          3      15       4      3
```

I want the following results:

```
Store   Orders  Good    Shorted  
A          2      0        2  
B          3      2        1
```

This shows that store A had 2 orders, both of which were not completely fulfilled while store B had 3 orders, 2 of which were fulfilled and 1 which was not.

I'm looking for a way to do this without using a bunch of expensive sub-queries.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE Ordered < Shipped`.

Comment: Count over a CASE: `count(distinct case when ordered <= shipped then orderid end)`

Comment: What happens if in an order with two items, the first one is shorted by 1 and the second one is long by 10? Is the order still short? Please add this case to your example data.

Comment: @TheImpaler: I doubt there's an order where you get a higher quatity than ordered.

Comment: Just to clarify, as long as ONE item within an order has shipped less than ordered, then that order counts as a shorted order.  Shipping more of another item doesn't counteract that.  So, in my example, order 1 for store A has two items, one of which was shorted.  That means that entire order was shorted.  Order 2 for store A also had one item shorted, so that order is shorted as well.  For store B none of the items in orders 1 and 2 were shorted, so both of those orders are good, but the item in order 3 was shorted, so that order is shorted.

Comment: Thanks, dnoeth!  That should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with a view or Sub-query. Here is my solution with a view:

```
Create view eachOrder as 
  select store, OrderID, sum(Ordered) as O, sum(Shipped) as s 
  from test 
  group by store, OrderID;

select store, 
    count(distinct orderid) as orders, 
    sum(case when o <= s then 1 else 0 end) as good,
    sum(case when o > s then 1 else 0 end) as shorted  
  from eachOrder 
  group by store;
```

Here is my solution as a sub query:

```
select
  store,
  count(distinct orderid) as orders,
  sum(case when o <= s then 1 else 0 end) as good,
  sum(case when o > s then 1 else 0 end) as shorted 
  from (select store, OrderID, 
          sum(Ordered) as O, 
          sum(Shipped) as s 
        from test 
        group by store, OrderID
      ) as EachOrder
  group by store;
```

You can see both solutions [here](https://paiza.io/projects/_0nkAIwfT2mzYKoehol0KA?language=mysql) https://paiza.io/projects/_0nkAIwfT2mzYKoehol0KA?language=mysql

Comment: Thank you Kishi!  I was trying to avoid subqueries because of the added overhead, but I think it's the only way.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Simply count over a CASE:

```
SELECT
  store,
  Count(DISTINCT orderid) AS orders,
  Sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ordered <= shipped THEN orderid END) AS good,
  Sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ordered > shipped THEN orderid END) AS shorted 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY store
```

Or to cut three distinct counts down to two:

```
SELECT store, orders, good, orders - good AS shorted
FROM
 (
   SELECT
     store,
     Count(DISTINCT orderid) AS orders,
     Sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ordered <= shipped THEN orderid END) AS good
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY store
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score 0):

use  subquery

```
    select t.Store,t.Orders,good,shorted from
(select  Store,count(*) as Orders
     from
     (select distinct Store,OrderID
    from table
     ) a group  by Store
) t
     join
     ( select store,
sum(case when ordered < shipped then 1  else 0 end) as good,
  sum(case when ordered > shipped then 1 else 0 end) as shorted 
from my_table group by store
     ) b on t.store=b.store
```